# C++ Using inheritance to tweak an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, inheritance

Since Dijkstra's algorithm and Prim's algorithm are so similar, I'd like to make a base algorithm class (I'll call it "Greedy" or something) and then I want to inherit from Greedy and tweak the algorithm based on the class.

I think it boils down to this.  I'd like to reuse a large portion of an algorithm but tweak an operation or two.

```
class BaseAlg
{
public:
    BaseAlg(std::vector<int> data)  //constructor sums a vector and stores result
    {
        int accum = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
            accum += data[i];
        result = accum;
    }

protected:
    int result;
};

class Alg1  //A second, similar algorithm
{
public:
    Alg1(std::vector<int> data)
    {
        //I want to reuse BaseAlg except use *= instead of +=; 
    }
};
```

So one way to do this is to only have one class (BaseAlg) and to add a "Selector" value to the class's constructor.  I would switch on that selector value and execute += or *= in different cases.  I feel like there should be a way to implement this reuse with inheritance because there is an "is a" relationship between Greedy and Prim and Greedy and Dijkstra. But I can't quite figure it out.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer it template meta-programming

Comment: Try [Modern C++ Design](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315) for good examples of how to do this sort of thing with zero run-time overhead. Old, but one of the best C++ books around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use templates for this kind of "reuse but nor really inheritance".

For instance, in your case, basically it boils down to this:

```
template<class Op, class Iter, class T> T reduce(const Op & op, Iter begin, Iter end, T init = T()) {
    T accum = init;
    for(Iter i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        accum = Op(accum, *i);
    return accum;
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> data; // fill data
int sum = reduce(add<int>, data.begin(), data.end());
int prod = reduce(mul<int>, data.begin(), data.end(), 1);
```

where you'd need to define `add` and `mult` like this:

```
template<class T> T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
template<class T> T mult(T a, T b) { return a * b; }
```

Now, this was all for illustrative purpose, as Jerry Coffin pointed out, with the STL you can simply do:

```
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
int sum = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0, std::plus<int>);
```

Comment: Just don't use these directly, since your `reduce` is already in the standard library as `std::accumulate` (and it also had analogs of your `add` and `mult`).

Comment: Indeed, this is to illustrate. Not sure it even compiles ;)

Comment: You're welcome. If you're interested in design, I second anjruu's recommendation "Modern C++ Design", and also have a look at the associated [loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net) library's code.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, which [is not particularly appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/206447). You should provide sufficient information about the pattern so reading up on it on Wikipedia or elsewhere is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd go with Antoin's solution, the inheritance might also work (but it looks crappy):

```
class BaseAlg {
public:
   BaseAlg () : result (0) {}
   virtual ~BaseAlg () {}

   int Accumulate (std::vector<int>& data) {
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
         result = func (accum, data[i]);
      return result;
   }
protected:
   virtual int func (int a, int b) = 0;
private:
   int result;
};

class AlgMult : public BaseAlg {
private:
   virtual int func (int a, int b) {
      return a*b;
   }
};

class AlgSum : public BaseAlg {
private:
   virtual int func (int a, int b) {
      return a+b;
   }
};
```

Comment: yeah you can certainly do this, but you get a virtual call to a very small function in a tight loop which is quite a bit slower.

Comment: Indeed it's not efficient by any means, and overall ugly, but topicstarter wanted it to be implemented using inheritance :-) So, here it is. In real life I would use std::accumulate customized with function or functor.