# Doubts about classes and polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, hash, polymorphism

I'm trying to build a hash table class in C++ using the chaining method, a minimal example class is:

```
template <class V>                                                                  
class HashTable {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
private:                                                                                                       
  //some parameters to define the hash_table                                                                                                  
  HashFunc * h;  //family of hash functions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                       
  /*other functions*/                                                                       
};
```

I'm having some troubles with the member `HashFunc * h`, which is the hash function I intend to use to store pairs <key,value> in the hash table. In my `main`, I need to build two different hash tables, one which hashes integers and another one which hashes strings.

My doubts are:

1. A natural choice for me would be to use polymorphism for the hash function in the following way (mind that I have limited experience with classes and polymorphism):

```
class HashFunc{
public:
  virtual int operator()()=0;
}
    
class IntegerHashFunc: public HashFunc
{
  //parameters to hash integers
 public:
  int operator()(int x){
    //operations for integer hashing
  }
}

class StringHashFunc: public HashFunc
{
  //parameters to hash strings
  IntegerHashFunc h_integer; //string->integer->integer hash
  public:
    int operator()(string name){
      int result=0;
      //operations for string hashing
      return h_integer(result); //I need to hash the integer resulting from string "hashing"
    }
}
```

But this won't work because the `operator()(string name)` in `StringHashFunc` has different arguments and thus doesn't override the `virtual` method in the base class. How to make this work?

2. I'm not sure on how to make this work in the constructor for the `HashTable` class: how to choose between the two methods? Should I just use a flag in the constructor like:

```
template<class V>
HashTable<V>::HashTable(/*args*/, int flag){
  //other parameters
  switch(flag){
    case 1:
      h=new IntegerHashFunc(/*args for integer hashing*/);
    case 2:
      h=new StringHashFunc(/*args for string hashing*/);
  }
}
```

or is there a better way?

3. Is there a better and more natural way to do what I want to do? For example, I tried using a single class `HashFunc` with two overloads `operator()(int)` and `operator()(string)`, but I don't want to "carry" around string parameters and methods if I'm working just with integers.

Comment: "A natural choice for me would be to use polymorphism". NO. Stop right here and think again. Do any standard library containers use polymorphism? Why or why not?

Comment: one `HashTable` is supposed to hold a `StringHashFunc` and a `IntHashFunc` or do you always have only hash functions for one type?

Comment: I second pronouns, coming from a different language it took me some time to appreciate C++, now runtime-polymorphis is my last resort, not the goto-solution like in other languages

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I don't really know to be honest, what would be eventual issues here? So what do you suggest?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127392/c-using-inheritance-to-tweak-an-algorithm

Comment: @idclev463035818 one `HashTable` should always have only one type of hash function

Comment: if `V` is that type then you want `HashTable<V>` to hold eg a `std::vector< HashFunction<V> >` and `HashFunction<V>` has an `operator()(const V&)`

Comment: @idclev463035818 one hash table is either with `StringHashFunc` or `IntHashFunc`.

Comment: do you need such two `HashTable`s (the one for `int` and the one for `string`) to be of the same type?

Comment: in different words: Do you choose to hash `int` or `string` at runtime or at compile time? In your code it looks like a bit of both

Comment: You could get some inspiration from [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Templates is the way to go here. You don't even need a `HashFunc` class or anything. The way the std-library handles it you can pass anything (function,  lamba, structure) as long it can be called like a function.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I actually need it at compile time, which made me realize runtime polymorphism was a bad choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR - the answer to all questions is "use templates, not polymorphism".

> A natural choice for me would be to use polymorphism for the hash function in the following way (mind that I have limited experience with classes and polymorphism):
> But this won't work because the operator()(string name) in StringHashFunc has different arguments and thus doesn't override the virtual method in the base class. How to make this work?

You cannot. In order to make the derived class non abstract, you need to override all pure virtual functions. And even if you add another overload with parameter, it doesn't help, because you can't call those overloads with base class pointer.
Theoretically, you can do `dynamic_cast` to determine what the actual type is (in a long, long chain of `if` statements), but that's discouraged.

> I'm not sure on how to make this work in the constructor for the HashTable class: how to choose between the two methods? Should I just use a flag in the constructor like:
> or is there a better way?

One option would be to use type traits to select the right branch (assuming you really, really want to use polymorphism):

```
if(std::is_same_v<V, int>) 
    h=new IntegerHashFunc(/*args for integer hashing*/);
else if(std::is_same_v<V, std::string>)
    h=new StringHashFunc(/*args for string hashing*/);
```

> Is there a better and more natural way to do what I want to do? For example, I tried using a single class HashFunc with two overloads operator()(int) and operator()(string), but I don't want to "carry" around string parameters and methods if I'm working just with integers.

Yes, use templates, like the standard library hash table (aka. [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) does:

```
template<typename T>
class HashFunc{
public:
  int operator()(const T&) const;
};

template<>
class HashFunc<int>{
public:
  int operator()(const int&) const {
    // do calculations for int
  }
};

template<>
class HashFunc<std::string>{
public:
  int operator()(const std::string&) const {
    // do calculations for std::string
  }
};

//etc... for all other specializations

template <class V>                                                                  
class HashTable {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
private:                                                                                                       
  //some parameters to define the hash_table                                                                                                  
  HashFunc<V> h;  //family of hash functions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                       
  /*other functions*/                                                                       
};
```

Or better yet, use the already existing [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), which does exactly this, but is already implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know about `std::unordered_map`, this is just an exercise on implementing data structures.

Comment: You can also make sure that `HashTable<float>` would not compile by using `static_assert` like this (inside the ctor for example): `public: HashFunc() { static_assert( std::is_same<T,int>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, "Oops bad hash");}`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have a doubt though: `HashFunc<int>` and `HashFunc<string>` have constructors with different numbers of arguments, how can I deal with this in the main class `HashTable`?

Comment: @luigi It depends on how do you determine those. Where do you get those arguments from (i.e. how does `HashTable` know what to pass to those `HashFunc`) and why they can't be initialized as defaults in `HashFunc` specializations?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I need to choose them at runtime and pass as inputs. The `HashFunc<int>` needs 4 arguments while the `HashFunc<string>` needs 3.

Comment: @luigi If HashFunc objects cannot be made default constructible, I suggest passing an already built object of HashFunc to HashTable. You could accept any number of arguments in HashTable constructor using [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and construct HashFunc object from that, but that would go (slightly) against the Single Responsibility rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use policy based design and it will be much simpler.

First create your hash functions objects:

```
struct IntegerHashFunc
{
  int operator()(int x){ return x; }
};

struct StringHashFunc
{
  IntegerHashFunc h_integer; //string->integer->integer hash
    int operator()(string name){
      int result=0;
      return h_integer(result);
    }
};
```

Your `HashTable` class will take the Hash function as a template parameter.

```
template <typename Key, typename Val, typename HashFunctionPolicy = IntegerHashFunc>
class HashTable {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
private:                                                                                                       
  //some parameters to define the hash_table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
public:                                                                                                       
  /*other functions*/
  void somefunction(Key key)
  {
      HashFunctionPolicy f;
      auto x = f(key);
  }                                                                   
};
```